# Efficiency of an Internal Combustion Engine

Tags: thermodynamics

This question is about How correct are those comments on efficiecy of internal combustion(IC) engines which calcuate it using 2nd law of thermodynamics.The maximum efficiency of a heat engine can be determined by second law. But the second law says you can't convert heat completely into work in a cyclic manner.It is not the case with ic engines since the working substance(fuel+air) doesn't follow any cycle. So there should not be any limitation imposed by 2nd law on IC engines.

Comment: 1. Please explain abbreviations like "ic engine" 2. I don't see an explicit question here.

Comment: The piston goes in and the piston comes out - how is that not a cycle?

Comment: You should probably take a look at wiki articles on the [Otto cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_cycle) and the [Diesel cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Diesel_cycle).

Comment: @jon custer a thermodynamic cycle is when working substance attains its initial state. In IC engines the working substance is exhausted rather than completeing the cycle.

Comment: Yet, somehow, the Otto cycle is in every thermodynamics book.  As is the steam engine.  Both of which 'exhaust' the working substance as part of the cycle.

Comment: So what kind of cycle is  stated in kelvin planck statement of 2nd law. Is it a mechanical or a thermodynamic cycle (or both).